# read_csv stops reading some lines eventhough with the same formats

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a csv file with 4 lines with exactly same formatting. while reading the csv with panda it does not read all the lines. I am not able to figure out why ? as the formats are the same.Plz help.  Listed below:

```
tmp_csv_outfile:
6801 2017/09/28 18:56:51.390624 129.1972 107 XXX1 YYYY ZZZZ 908 log warn verbose 1 908 :: 235 :: [tp]0022 > f4 37 3e 00 00 
6802 2017/09/28 18:56:51.390640 129.1972 108 XXX1 YYYY ZZZZ 908 log warn verbose 1 908 :: 235 :: [tp] TEST: ~Finished Testcase: TEST0471
6803 2017/09/28 18:56:51.390646 129.1973 109 XXX1 YYYY ZZZZ 908 log warn verbose 1 908 :: 235 :: [dia] trigger received - resetting session timeout 5000
6804 2017/09/28 18:56:51.390652 129.1975 110 XXX1 YYYY ZZZZ 908 log info verbose 1 908 :: 235 :: [dia][th1] Diagnosis Core responded, sending to the th1 Adapter (allConnected = 0)



df = pd.read_csv(tmp_csv_outfile,names=["Data"],header=None,sep='\s\s+$',engine='python')
print df.tail(3)
```

output

```
                                                Data
0  6801 2017/09/28 18:56:51.390624 129.1972 107 X...
1  6802 2017/09/28 18:56:51.390640 129.1972 108 X...
```

**SOLUTION** **SOVLED**

After a long digging in I found the solution at 
https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/16893

After a update of the pandas it starts working fine. Thanks @ jezrael for valuable inputs.

Comment: If use `sep='|'` or `sep='¥‎'` still problem?

Comment: But I dont have other sep patterns.It is working for almost all the lines execpt what happens the case here with line second. If I change it to the last line then it works fine. or did I understood you wrong ?

Comment: Yes, problem is with data - your data after  `235 ::` are mesh, so it seems data are joined with another row or row is removed...My solution does not work?

Comment: The issue cannot be [replicated](https://repl.it/M9nd/0) with the data you provided. There might be non-printable characters in your file that are causing the problem.

Comment: @ Goyo : in my notepad++ I could see two special charactors "SUB"~"DC1" in line number two. I think these got removed some how while pasting in this page. [Charactors before and after '~']

Comment: +1 @ jezrael : both the separators '|' & '¥' suggested by you and the one used by me '\s\s+$' work fine only after I have updated the pandas revision as stated in the github issue mentioned. Anyway thanks for these ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think problem is with separator, so change it to some value which is not in data:

```
df = pd.read_csv(tmp_csv_outfile, names=["Data"], sep='¥‎', engine='python')
print (df)

                                                Data
0  6801 2017/09/28 18:56:51.390624 129.1972 107 X...
1  6802 2017/09/28 18:56:51.390640 129.1972 108 X...
2  6803 2017/09/28 18:56:51.390646 129.1973 109 X...
3  6804 2017/09/28 18:56:51.390652 129.1975 110 X...
```

EDIT:

With real data for me working nice:

```
df = pd.read_csv('faulty.csv', sep='|', names=['Data'])
print (df)
                                                Data
0  6801 2017/09/28 18:56:51.390624 129.1972 107 X...
1  6802 2017/09/28 18:56:51.390640 129.1972 108 X...
2  6803 2017/09/28 18:56:51.390646 129.1973 109 X...
3  6804 2017/09/28 18:56:51.390652 129.1975 110 X...
```

Comment: @ jezrael : forgive my ignorance. I am not able find the symbol which you have used as a separator. I also checked python RE. Plz point me where to find this info. Thanks.

Comment: You need symbol which is not in data, because `Data` is only one column. So I use `yen` - `¥‎` ;)

Comment: @ jezrael : Great method to cheat the parsing. :).  I managed now to do as you have said. But I am sorry to say that it did not work for me. May be I have different characters which are removed when I pasted the code. These are "SUB" and "DC1" which are before and after the '~' in line 2.

Comment: Is possible send me your file with 5 rows to my email in my profile?

Comment: @ jezrael, sent. Thanks.

Comment: @ jezrael : I have now changed my sep to 'yen' from '\s\s+$'.

Comment: But `df = pd.read_csv('faulty.csv', sep='|', names=['Data'])` working perfectly

Comment: yes, but works only after updating the pandas version.